# I have a Windows 10 Microsoft account, how do I make the username name seperate from the Microsoft account's name?

Tags: windows-10

Sorry if I didn't word the title too well, when I'm tired i can't type that much. My problem is that I want my Windows username to be different from my Microsoft account name (example. Microsoft account name is 800millimeters on ms, Windows username is john simons) other posts here tell me to use netwizpl although every time I log back out and sign in the name changes back to the Microsoft account name. Any fixes for this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Any fixes for this?" - Yes; Disconnect the Microsoft Account from the local account.  You will be given a prompt to provide a name to your profile.  Once you log out of your profile and back into your profile, connect the Microsoft Account to your profile, once you finish that process your profile name will be John.Smith instead of whatever the username of your Microsoft Account is.  If you mean something else you will have to edit your question and clarify it. I have previously submitted this answer to a question hence the reason I am not submitting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that I want my Windows username to be different from my
> Microsoft account name (example. Microsoft account name is
> 800millimeters on ms, Windows username is john simons)

For your Microsoft Account, there is an email address (as you showed) and then in the Microsoft Account Setup

https://account.microsoft.com/profile

you can set a First Name and Last Name.

So I suggest you set up your name and then that is what will be used for your Microsoft Account (even at computer Log In).

That is the limit of what you can do with a Microsoft Account.

Failing that, you may need to use a Local Account instead. You can convert your Microsoft Account login to a local account and that should allow you to keep all the data in your profile.